# How to use `biglasso` in a nested regression modeling using reformulate?

Tags: r, nested, large-data, lasso-regression

I'm trying to do `lasso` regression modeling in R using `biglasso` package. I have a dataframe of 100000 rows and 51 columns. The first few columns are response variables and the rest of the columns are predictor variables.
Previously I used `reformulate` function for doing nested modeling for `lm`, `glm`, and `ranger`. But that is not working when implementing in `biglasso`.

```
head(GC05cr_h16_dat3)
# A tibble: 7 × 25
EE87865ln1   EE87866ln1   EE87895ln1  blood_vessel_h16 adrenal_gland_h16 bone_element_h16 bronchus_h16 
       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>             <dbl>            <dbl>        <dbl>         
1    0.00391     0.00326    0.00332       0                 0                1            0             
2    0.00139     0.00116    0.00132       0                 0                0            0             
3    0.00360     0.00270    0.00469       1                 1                0            1             
4    0.00323     0.00348    0.00339       0                 0                1            0             
5    0.00323     0.00330    0.00382       0                 1                0            0             
6    0.00278     0.00208    0.00214       0                 0                1            0
```

What I did for `lm` and `ranger` is that,

```
all_variables <- names(GC05cr_h16_dat3)
response_variables <- all_variables[c(1, 3)]
predictors <- all_variables[-c(1, 3)]

lm_models <- lapply(
  response_variables,
  function(x) lm(reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = x), data = GC05cr_h16_dat3)
) |>
  setNames(response_variables)
```

Now, if we could loop over the column of `j matrix` one after another , we could make `lasso` modeling for all predictors.

```
  j1 <- data.matrix(GC05cr_h16_dat3[, 1])
  j2 <- data.matrix(GC05cr_h16_dat3[, 2])
  j <- data.matrix(SLE28sy_w20_dat3[, c(1:3)])

  l <-  data.matrix(GC05cr_h16_dat3[, -c(1:3)])
  l.bm = as.big.matrix(l)
  
  
  fit1bl <- biglasso(l.bm, j1)
  fit2bl <- biglasso(l.bm, j2)
```